# Show that the transformation $T:P_n\rightarrow P_n$ defined by $T(p(x))=p(x-2)$ is an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that the transformation $T:P_n\rightarrow P_n$ defined by $T(p(x))=p(x-2)$ is an isomorphism.

As my idea: let $p(x)=1\rightarrow T(p(x))=p(x-2)=1=1\cdot 1+0\cdot x+0\cdot x^2+\ldots\\
 p(x)=x\rightarrow T(p(x))=x-2=-2\cdot 1+1\cdot x+0\cdot x^2 +\ldots\\
p(x)=x^2\rightarrow T(p(x))=(x-2)^2=4\cdot 1+(-4)\cdot x+1\cdot x^2+0\cdot x^3+\ldots$

But I can't move further to find the matrix relative to the basis of $P_n$ and showing that $T$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: In a finite dimensional space, a homomorphism is an isomorphism if and only if the kernel...

Comment: @pjs36..is that kernal contain only zero

Comment: Yes, so I don't think you even need to think about bases here; there should be a basis-free way to verify that the map is a homomorphism, and that its kernel is trivial.

Comment: @pjs...thankn you can you give me hint to how find kernal

Comment: Hint: This transformation shifts the graph of $p$ 2 units to the right. Can you find the inverse transformation given that?

Comment: @pjs.kno i am trying but i cant

Comment: It’s the transformation that shifts 2 units *left*. Can you figure out how to express that in similar terms to the definition of $T$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint;**

Just check it is linear using *Taylor's formula* at order $n$ near $-2$ (it is an *exact* formula for polynomials) and find the inverse isomorphism.

In this case, Taylor's formula becomes
$$\bigl(T(p)\bigr)(x)=p(x-2)=p(-2)+p'(-2)x+\frac{p''(-2)}2x^2+\dots+\frac{p^{(n)}(-2)}{n!}x^n.$$

Comment: ....sorry i did't get idea with idea can you please little explanation

Comment: I added how Taylor's formula works in this case. Is that clearer?

Comment: @Bernard..sorry i am  have not getting any idea..i am really sorry

Comment: You don't have to be sorry. We're trying to help solving, not give full solution, and sometimes it's harder. Taylor's formula is useful only to find the matrix of $T$, not to prove it's an isomorphism. Isn't is clear to you $T $ is linear?

Comment: @Bernard..yes i am okay with T is linear

Comment: @Bernard...sorry i am not okay with T is linear

Comment: $T(p+q)=T(p)+T(q)$  simply means that $(p+q)(x-2)=p(x-2)+q(x-2)$, and similarly for $T(\lambda p)=\lambda T(p)$.

Comment: ..ok i got clarification about linear

Comment: There remains to find $T^{-1}(p)$, which has the form $p(x-a)$ for some $a$.

Comment: @Bernard...so now we have to fiknd T^-1

Comment: It's not hard to guess how to get back $p(x) $ from $p(x-2)$.